# Javascript phone number to letters

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want that it print a phonenumber in letters.

```js
var getal = new Array();
getal[0] = 'nul';
getal[1] = 'een';
getal[2] = 'twee';
getal[3] = 'drie';
getal[4] = 'vier';
getal[5] = 'vijf';
getal[6] = 'zes';
getal[7] = 'zeven';
getal[8] = 'acht';
getal[9] = 'negen';
telefoonnummer = prompt("What is your phone number?");
document.write("<br>" + telefoonnummer);
```

When you type in '12345678' I want that it prints 'one two three four five six seven eight'

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/5tt7d3e6/

Answer (score 1):

break the phonenumber and replace each characters with equivalent word

```js
       var getal = ['nul','een','twee','drie','vier','vijf','zes','zeven','acht','negen'];

        telefoonnummer = prompt("What is your phone number?");
        telefoonnummerwords = telefoonnummer.split("").map(x=>getal[x]).join(" "); 
        document.write("<br>" + telefoonnummerwords);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an object instead of an array. Once the user enters an input `split` the input and then use `map` to iterate over it. On each iteration use the element to get relevant value from the object. Then use `join` with delimiter white space to create a string

```js
var getal = {
  0: 'nul',
  1: 'een',
  2: 'twee',
  3: 'drie',
  4: 'vier',
  5: 'vijf',
  6: 'zes',
  7: 'zeven',
  8: 'acht',
  9: 'negen'
}
let telefoonnummer = prompt("What is your phone number?");
let k = telefoonnummer.trim().split('').map(function(item) {
  return getal[item]
}).join(' ');
document.write("<br>" + k);
```